# Centripetal force and frequency

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, frequency, centripetal-force

In uniform circular motion, for my lab, I used the formula  $_=4\pi^2 m r \times$(2) to find the experimental centripetal force

and I use $F_{cp}= 4\pi^2mr$  to find the theoretical value of $F_c$.
 I ended up with the same value of $F_c$.

I concluded that frequency does not affect that much the centripetal force but I do not have enough arguments. can I get help on this please?

Comment: Please use Latex to format your formulas. Also, what kind of system are you looking at and what is $f_2$? What is your exact question? With the information given it's almost impossible to give an answer.

Comment: the theoretical formula does not generally looks like that; it is $F=m\omega^2r$... And your "experimental" centripetal force formula is just a duplicate of the theoretical one, as $2\pi f$ is just $\omega$.

Comment: What is (f2)? Also, the unit of mass x length is not force (your 2nd equation). Are there terms missing in your question?

Comment: $F_{cp}= 4\pi^2mr$ try to apply basic dimensional analysis and you should see some issues.

Answer (score 1):

The centripetal force acting on a body of mass $m$ in uniform circular motion located at a distance $r$ from the axis of rotation is:
$$F_{c} = m\omega^2 r = m(2\pi f)^2 r = 4\pi^2 f^2 m r$$

Here, $\omega$ is the angular frequency of rotation and $f$ is the number of rotations per second.

The only way you arrived at your conclusion is because  $f=1$. Coming to such a conclusion that the  frequency does not affect the centripetal force that much is highly erroneous as it is apparent from the relation that the centripetal force varies as frequency squared.